# How to exec action typeText() with React Native TextInput outside screen (position: absolute, right: -99)

Tags: detox

I have TextInput outside screen with style {position: 'absolute', right: -99},
When i call action typeText(), i receive this error

"Error: Error: Cannot perform action due to constraint(s) failure.
Exception with Action: {
  "Action Name" : "Tap",
  "Element Description" : "",
  "Failed Constraint(s)" : "interactable",
  "All Constraint(s)" : "(!(isSystemAlertViewShown) && ((respondsToSelector(isAccessibilityElement) && isAccessibilityElement) || kindOfClass('UIView')) && (enabled && !(((kindOfClass('UIView') || respondsToSelector(accessibilityContainer)) && ancestorThatMatches(!(enabled))))) && interactable)",
  "Recovery Suggestion" : "Adjust element properties so that it matches the failed constraint(s)."
}

[
  {
    "Description" : "Cannot perform action due to constraint(s) failure.",
    "Error Domain" : "com.google.earlgrey.ElementInteractionErrorDomain",
    "Error Code" : "1",
    "File Name" : "GREYBaseAction.m",
    "Function Name" : "-[GREYBaseAction satisfiesConstraintsForElement:error:]",
    "Line" : "66"
  }
]
"
How can i do execute action typeText() with React Native TextInput outside screen

Comment: Detox: 5.8.1 - Node: 8.4.0 - RN: 0.47.2 - ios: 10.3.1 - Xcode: 9.2

Answer (score 0):

In order for Detox to interact with an element, the element needs to pass visibility criteria. I think the standard is 75% visibility.

[detox/docs/Introduction.WritingFirstTest.md](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/6a5b528fecaa598142adb1c595054a26220dfec3/docs/Introduction.WritingFirstTest.md)

> Note that the visibilty matcher makes sure the element is actually visible on screen (at least 75% of it to be exact). If it appears under the fold (eg. the user has to scroll to see it), this specific matcher will fail.

So in summary I don't see how it's possible to type text when the input field is outside the screen.